# Entity without translation

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

I want to make entity in Drupal 8 called `cash` that store only numeric value (integer or float). I think, that entity not need translation.
Is it possible for us to create custom entity without language/translation?

Answer (score 0):

@IgorTengab
An entity in Drupal 8 needs translation to be enabled to be translatable

For example by going to `/admin/structure/types/manage/ENTITYNAME` > language settings > enable translation

For more info [look here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multilingual/translating-content)

But for your purpose perhaps a light-weight alternative would be to create a custom entity https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/create-a-custom-content-entity